# flutter on mac desktop "No devices detected"

Tags: flutter

I have run:

```
export ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP=true
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

Then on flutter doctor i get no devices available:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.10.15-pre.357, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-IL)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.39.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

Did I miss anything? (I'm looking to develop a desktop app so not android emulator / ios emulator)

Comment: Full answer below, but see also my comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547971/flutter-desktop-build-fails-with-com-apple-xcode-tools-swift-compiler where I previously pointed out that you were using obsolete instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever instructions you are following are out of date;  `ENABLE_FLUTTER_DESKTOP` hasn't been the supported or documented way to enable experimental desktop support for several months (and the legacy code for it was recently removed). You need to enable it with `flutter config` as [documented in the official instructions](https://flutter.dev/desktop#tooling)

Answer (score 4):

Just Enable flutter desktop

`flutter config --enable-macos-desktop`